# How to define a custom operator/rule to convert $f(t-a) g(x-t-b)$ into $f(t-a) g(x-a-b)$?

Tags: programming, rule, custom-notation

I want to define a rule or an operator such that I can have an input like

```
Sin[t-2]Cos[x-5](z-x-t-9)^2 //.someRule
```

to get the output

```
Sin[t-2]Cos[x-5](z-16)^2.
```

---

Edit:

I have tried the code provided by @kglr:

```
ClearAll[op]

op = Function[, Module[{inactive = Inactivate @ #, replace},
    replace = ReplaceAll @ Catenate @ Map[Splice @ Solve[# == 0] &] @
       Activate @ Apply[List] @ MapApply[List] @ Most[inactive]; 
    Activate @ MapAt[replace, inactive, {-1}]], HoldFirst];
```

and tried it on example:

```
op[Sin[t - 2] (z - x - t - 9)^2]
```

to get error messages:

```
Splice::string: String expected at position 1 in Splice[{{t->ConditionalExpression[2+2 \[Pi] C[<<1>>],C[1]\[Element]Integers]},{t->ConditionalExpression[2+\[Pi]+2 \[Pi] C[<<1>>],C[1]\[Element]Integers]}}]. >>

Catenate::invrp: The argument Splice[{{t->ConditionalExpression[2+2 \[Pi] C[<<1>>],C[1]\[Element]Integers]},{t->ConditionalExpression[2+\[Pi]+2 \[Pi] C[<<1>>],C[1]\[Element]Integers]}}] is not a valid Association or a list. >>

ReplaceAll::reps: {Catenate[{Splice[{{t->ConditionalExpression[<<2>>]},{t->ConditionalExpression[<<2>>]}}]}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
```

with output of

```
    -Sin[2 - t] ReplaceAll[
   Catenate[{Splice[{{t -> 
         ConditionalExpression[2 + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
          C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {t -> 
         ConditionalExpression[2 + \[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1], 
          C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}]}]][(-9 - t - x + z)^2]
```

I use Mathematica version 10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** modified to work with version 10.0:

```
ClearAll[opV10]

opV10 = Function[, 
   Module[{inactive = Inactivate @ #, replace}, 
    replace = 
     ReplaceAll[#, 
       Flatten @ Map[Sequence @@ Solve[# == 0] &] @
         Activate @ (List @@ (List @@@ Most[inactive]))] &;
    Activate @ MapAt[replace, inactive, {-1}]], HoldFirst];
```

***Examples:***

```
opV10[Sin[t - 2] (z - x - t - 9)^2]
```

> ```
>  -(-11 - x + z)^2 Sin[2 - t]
> ```

```
opV10[Sin[t - 2] Cos[x - 5] (z - x - t - 9)^2]
```

> ```
>  -(-16 + z)^2 Cos[5 - x] Sin[2 - t]
> ```

```
opV10[Sin[t - 2] Cos[x - 5] FOO[w + 50] (z - x - t - w - 9)^2]
```

> ```
>  -(34 + z)^2 Cos[5 - x] FOO[50 + w] Sin[2 - t]
> ```

---

**Original answer:**

Maybe something like:

```
ClearAll[op]

op = Function[, Module[{inactive = Inactivate @ #, replace},
    replace = ReplaceAll @ Catenate @ Map[Splice @ Solve[# == 0] &] @
       Activate @ Apply[List] @ MapApply[List] @ Most[inactive]; 
    Activate @ MapAt[replace, inactive, {-1}]], HoldFirst];
```

***Examples:***

```
op[Sin[t - 2] (z - x - t - 9)^2]
```

> ```
> -(-11 - x + z)^2 Sin[2 - t]
> ```

```
op[Sin[t - 2] Cos[x - 5] (z - x - t - 9)^2]
```

> ```
>  -(-16 + z)^2 Cos[5 - x] Sin[2 - t]
> ```

```
op[Sin[t - 2] Cos[x - 5] FOO[w + 50] (z - x - t - w - 9)^2]
```

> ```
>  -(34 + z)^2 Cos[5 - x] FOO[50 + w] Sin[2 - t]
> ```

Comment: I have tried the code but it gives a lot of error messages.

Comment: could be version/os related. I am using _"13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"_. Could you edit your post to add an example that gives error messages?

Comment: I just edited the post and attached the error messages.

Comment: Mohamed, please see if the updated version works in your version/os.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works beautifully.

Comment: Mohamed, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.